# get a list of all models from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need a list with all models (class_names) which have the pattern "Cube" at the end.

example:

all my models:
ModelFoo, ModelBar, ModelBarCube, Mode2BarCube

what I need:

['ModelBarCube', 'Mode2BarCube']

Answer (score 24):

Since Rails doesn't load classes unless it needs them, you must read the models from the folder. Here is the code

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root + '/app/models/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
  @models = Object.subclasses_of(ActiveRecord::Base).select { |model| 
   model.name[-4..-1] == "Cube"
  }
```

Comment: This code works for me, except that I sometimes get warnings when I re-require a model file that was already required earlier. I was able to resolve this by using expand_path, see the bottom of http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/10/22/double-load-guards-in-ruby/

Comment: A little correction hope you don't mind, RAILS_ROOT has been changed to Rails.root

Answer (score 22):

in rails 3 you'd swap @models for:

```
@models = ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }.sort
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses is deprecated, use #descendants

Answer (score 8):

```
@models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map(&:name)
```

gives you all the model names which either inherit form `ActiveRecord::Base` or is a subclass of any existing model.

Comment: It gives not a full list of models

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 3

```
@models = ActiveRecord::Base.
    descendants.
    select{|x| x.name[-4..-1] == "Cube"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was googling answer how to show all Ralis models, combination of answers here was weary helpful, thx.

so here is combination of solutions that works even for STI tables on Rails

```
#Since Rails doesn't load classes unless it needs them, you must read the models from the folder. Here is the code
Dir[Rails.root.to_s + '/app/models/**/*.rb'].each do |file| 
  begin
    require file
  rescue
  end
end

models = ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }.sort

models.each do |model|
  print model
  print '  '
end
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1347687

Comment: example of usage https://github.com/equivalent/my_rails_monkeypatch_bunch/blob/master/automatic_guid_generator/lib/tasks/guid.rake