# Rails console how do I 'show tables' like I would in mySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails so this might be easy but I don't see it documented anywhere.  I am trying to use the rails console to see what my database tables look like.  In mySQL I would type show tables; Is there a similar function in the rails console? I can see I have a ton of objects in my models folder and that is helpful, but what I really want to do is see what database tables are generated.

Comment: I usually look at db/schema.rb for this purpose. Not in the console but in an editor.

Comment: May be this post can help you..!! :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233692/get-a-list-of-all-models-from-rails

Comment: Turns out this was a duplicate question but thanks for the comments.